# Showing XML in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

i want to show a xml in a jsp page as it is. Currently when i am displaying it on a jsp page then it is removing all xml structure like nodes and just showing the content.
For eg.
for

```
    <file>
        <name>12345.pdf</name>
        <size>70725bytes</size>
        <isDirectory>No</isDirectory>
    </file>
```

It is showing on ui as only this:-

```
        <name>12345.pdf</name>
        <size>70725bytes</size>
        <isDirectory>No</isDirectory>
```

Comment: Where is the code of your JSP?

Comment: in servlet below is the code:-
request.setAttribute("outputDir", traceDirResp);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/TraceDirectory.jsp").forward(request, response);


in jsp page below is the code:-

<pre><c:out value="${outputDir}"/></pre>

Answer (score 0):

to be shown as text and not be interpreted as markup, `<` must be escaped. Escaping `>` is not absolutely required, but I would do it anyway:

```
&lt;file&gt;
    &lt;name&gt;12345.pdf&lt;/name&gt;
    etc.
```

If the XML is in fact store in a request attribute, you just need to escape it thanks to the JSTL c:out tag (just like **every** value that could contain special characters):

```
<c:out value="${theXmlString}"/>
```

Comment: Event after using <c:out value="${theXmlString}"/> , i am getting the same problem. can you suggest if i am going wrong somewhere because when i am taking output on console it is coming fine but when i pass it from servlet to jsp page for showing on jsp page it is not coming in exact xml format.

Comment: I can't tell if you're doing something wrong without seeing any single line of your code. Edit your question, and show your code.

Comment: in servlet below is the code:-     request.setAttribute("outputDir", traceDirResp); getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/TraceDirectory.jsp").forward(request, response); in jsp page below is the code:-     <pre><c:out value="${outputDir}"/></pre>

Answer (score 0):

put your tag between pre tags

```
out.print("<pre>"+yourXML+"</pre>");
```

it worked for me

Comment: Even inside a pre tag, the special characters must be escaped. It works only beause the browser tries to fix the errors for you.

Comment: Ya i had put the xml in cout between pre tags but this didn't workout for me. without Pre Tags it is showing whole xml in a single line.

Comment: @manish: that is expected. sequences of white spaces (including line breaks) are considered as a single space in HTML, unless they're inside a pre tag. So c:out properly escapes the brackets, and `<pre>` makes the browser display every character as a text editor would do.